# Pine Script ta.ema takes number arg?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The following code is in a popular script.

```
x = close
t = 12
avrng = ta.ema(math.abs(x - x[1]), t)
```

I'm no expert in Pine Script but it looks like ta.ema is passed a number, not a series as I believe it should be. I don't find that signature in the v5 docs, and I'm trying to figure out what the ema of a single number over a period would be anyway (but I'm probably interpreting wrong). Displaying a label with the values didn't help either. What's the breakdown of this simple code? It sure seems to work.

[ta.ema Docs](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dema)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [math.abs()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_math%7Bdot%7Dabs) can return a series, which implies type coalescing of the first argument to the ta.ema() function. I have to assume a hidden variable for this series is committed so that ta.ema has something to iterate across over the period length on every iteration. Will read more on the execution model.